# Создать словарь из списка определенным образом

Tags: python, list, матрицы, словари

Есть матрица значений и список ккординат.

Матрица значений:

```
[[ 33   0  33 229]
 [233 109 255 109]
 [ 60  72  60  59]
 [108   0 255  24]
 [ 59 229  77 108]
 [ 72  24  77 233]]
```

Список координат :

```
   coords = 
          [(1190, 135), (1352, 135), (1514, 135), (1676, 135)],
          [(1199, 297), (1352, 297), (1514, 297), (1676, 297)],
          [(1190, 459), (1352, 459), (1514, 459), (1676, 459)],
          [(1190, 621), (1352, 621), (1514, 621), (1676, 621)],
          [(1190, 783), (1352, 783), (1514, 783), (1676, 783)],
          [(1190, 945), (1352, 945), (1514, 945), (1676, 945)]
```

Значений в матрице *повторяются*, у каждого значений есть *пара*. Всего в матрице 12 пар, а значит 24 значения. В списке координат тоже 24 значения. 24 (x,y).

Задача:

Сформировать словарь вида : `{ значение: [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]}`

Конкретный пример с использованием списка и матрицы из условия:

```
{ 33:[(1190,135),(1514,135)],
   0:[(1352,135),(1352,621)],
 229:[(1676,135),(1352,783)],
 233:[(1199,297),(1676,945)],
 109:[(1352,297),(1676,297)],
 255:[(1514,297),(1514,621)],
  60:[(1190,459),(1514,459)],
  72:[(1352,459),(1190,945)],
  59:[(1676,459),(1190,783)],
 108:[(1190,621),(1676,783)],
  24:[(1676,621),(1352,945)],
  77:[(1514,783),(1514,945)]}
```

Тоесть теперь значений 12. Но у каждого значения теперь по 2 пары координат.

Приведу в пример значение 33 из матрицы.

33 это первое и третье значение в матрице, значит у него должна быть первая и третья координата.

```
33:[(1190,135),(1514,135)]
```

Надеюсь задача понятна, если нет, задавайте вопросы в комментариях.Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы предлагаете нам написать решение за вас? Или все-таки покажете свое, в котором что-то не получилось и попросите помочь исправить ошибку? Тем более, что в соседней теме вам задачу уже разжевали.

Comment: До ошибки дело не дошло, у меня затруднения на самом начале, я просто не знаю как это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

matrix = [[ 33, 0, 33, 229],
          [233, 109, 255, 109],
          [60, 72, 60, 59],
          [108, 0, 255, 24],
          [59, 229, 77, 108],
          [72, 24, 77, 233]]

coords = [(1190, 135), (1352, 135), (1514, 135), (1676, 135),
          (1199, 297), (1352, 297), (1514, 297), (1676, 297),
          (1190, 459), (1352, 459), (1514, 459), (1676, 459),
          (1190, 621), (1352, 621), (1514, 621), (1676, 621),
          (1190, 783), (1352, 783), (1514, 783), (1676, 783),
          (1190, 945), (1352, 945), (1514, 945), (1676, 945)]

new_dict = {}

for pos, item in enumerate(chain.from_iterable(matrix)):
  new_dict.setdefault(item, []).append(coords[pos]) 

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: `new_dict.setdefault(item, []).append(Cords.coords[pos])` Хм, ругается на эту строчку : list index out of range

Comment: @SuddenDumb https://repl.it/repls/AthleticNonstopOutliers

Comment: Понял, что то у меня не так

Comment: Нашел ошибку, лишние квадратные скобки открывающие и закрывающие coords

Comment: Вопрос, можно ли как-то разделисть две пары координат из словаря и записать их в список? Делаю так : `for key in new_dict:
      newcord.append(new_dict[key])` newcord - пустой список куда записываются координаты. Результат такой :`[(1190, 135), (1352, 459)]` а нужен такой : `[(1190, 135)] , [(1352, 459)]`

Comment: @SuddenDumb `new_dict[key]` возвращает список координат. Если надо с ним работать, то работайте как с обычным списком. Ещё можно `new_dict.values()` использовать для списка списков координат

Comment: Я имею ввиду что в словаре ккординаты хранятся парами тоесть одна ячейка словаря это [(1190, 135), (1352, 459)] , а мне их нужно разделить на 2 части, что-бы было [(1190, 135)] , [(1352, 459)]. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Что key что value, вывод один и тот же в данном случае

Comment: @SuddenDumb всё возможно. Но зачем вам списки, состоящие из одного элемента? `for coord_list in new_dict.values(): for item in coord_list`

Comment: Я всегда все не через то место делаю, а вообще мне просто нужно все координаты такого вида (xxxx , yyy) записать в словарь

Comment: Извиняюсь, в список конечно

Comment: @SuddenDumb у вас же уже есть список `coord` именно с такими координатами. Опять не понимаю, что вы хотите, лучше задайте новый вопрос

Comment: Это все делалось,что бы узнать координаты каждого значения в матрице, что-бы потом кликать по этим координатам, а в списке coord они записаны просто по возрастанию

Comment: Сейчас задам новый вопрос

Comment: Задал. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1143164/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8