# Перенос значений из словаря в список, с измененниями

Tags: python, список, координаты, словарь

Есть словарь `new_dict`:

```
{109: [(1190, 135), (1514, 459)], 233: [(1352, 135), (1514, 945)], 108: [(1514, 135), (1676, 459)], 59: [(1676, 135), (1190, 297)], 24: [(1352, 297), (1676, 621)], 60: [(1514, 297), (1352, 945)], 229: [(1676, 297), (1352, 783)], 72: [(1190, 459), (1190, 783)], 33: [(1352, 459), (1676, 783)], 77: [(1190, 621), (1514, 621)], 0: [(1352, 621), (1190, 945)], 255: [(1514, 783), (1676, 945)]}
```

Слева значение, справа 2 пары координат.

С помошью :

```
for key in new_dict:
    print(new_dict[key])
```

можно получить координаты:

```
[(1190, 135), (1676, 135)]
[(1352, 135), (1352, 459)]
[(1514, 135), (1514, 459)]
[(1190, 297), (1514, 783)]
[(1352, 297), (1676, 621)]
[(1514, 297), (1190, 459)]
[(1676, 297), (1676, 783)]
[(1676, 459), (1190, 783)]
[(1190, 621), (1514, 621)]
[(1352, 621), (1352, 945)]
[(1352, 783), (1676, 945)]
[(1190, 945), (1514, 945)]
```

Из этих координат нужно получить список вида:

```
new_coords = [(1190, 135), (1676, 135), (1352, 135), (1352, 459),
              (1514, 135), (1514, 459), (1190, 297), (1514, 783)...
```

Тоесть ключи словаря нужно как бы разделить на две части и записать в правильном порядке, слева направо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

new_dict = {109: [(1190, 135), (1514, 459)], 233: [(1352, 135), (1514, 945)], 108: [(1514, 135), (1676, 459)], 59: [(1676, 135), (1190, 297)], 24: [(1352, 297), (1676, 621)], 60: [(1514, 297), (1352, 945)], 229: [(1676, 297), (1352, 783)], 72: [(1190, 459), (1190, 783)], 33: [(1352, 459), (1676, 783)], 77: [(1190, 621), (1514, 621)], 0: [(1352, 621), (1190, 945)], 255: [(1514, 783), (1676, 945)]}
coords = list(chain.from_iterable(new_dict.values()))
```

Comment: Не до конца понимаю что тут есть что

Comment: Все идельно, единственное что нужно получить список с координатами, а не вывести на экран

Comment: @SuddenDumb, теперь в coords список координат. Но это уже такое.